# Pentaho - Big Query [Simba][BigQueryJDBCDriver](100032) Error executing query job. Message: BIGQUERY_API_ERR

Tags: google-bigquery, google-drive-api, pentaho, pdi, simba

In pentaho I get an error when I read a BigQuery table with a "Table Entry", I have these considerations:

1. This table was created from a Google Drive sheet with the service account
2. I can read this table with "Google Sheet Plugins"
   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9dl0.png
   [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCxQK.png

```
2022/07/29 21:20:36 - Select.0 - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : An error occurred, processing will be stopped: 
2022/07/29 21:20:36 - Select.0 - An error occurred executing SQL: 
2022/07/29 21:20:36 - Select.0 - select 1  from `ms-data-warehouse.ms_Dev_Staging.ET_ods_hour`
2022/07/29 21:20:36 - Select.0 - [Simba][BigQueryJDBCDriver](100032) Error executing query job. Message: BIGQUERY_API_ERR
2022/07/29 21:20:36 - Select.0 - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : Error initializing step [Select]
2022/07/29 21:20:36 - insert drive - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : Step [Select.0] failed to initialize!
2022/07/29 21:20:36 - Select.0 - Finished reading query, closing connection.
2022/07/29 21:20:36 - Spoon - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : insert drive: preparing transformation execution failed
2022/07/29 21:20:36 - Spoon - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException: 
2022/07/29 21:20:36 - Spoon - We failed to initialize at least one step.  Execution can not begin!
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second screenshot says that `it doesn't have the Drive access`.

BigQuery doesn't keep the credential for accessing the Google Drive, instead, BigQuery uses the "current user" credential trying to access Google Drive.

Apparently the "service account" has the Google Drive access (in order to create that table) but either your account or the account used to setup the Simba BigQueryJDBCDriver doesn't have the access to the Google Drive file.